# StripeInvalidRequestError: No such checkout.session when its clearly there

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, stripe-payments

Hey I get this error StripeInvalidRequestError: No such checkout.session: pi_3OjTAGAHrCXdaN2D11vQGxvG. The problem is that it's clearly defined both in my webhooks log and in my dashboard. It's the same id. The reason I am trying to retrieve it is so that I can check the session mode pictured in the webhooks endpoint below.

```
Webhooks logs => webhooks: payment succeeded {
  id: 'pi_3OjTAGAHrCXdaN2D11vQGxvG',
  object: 'payment_intent',
  amount: 200,
  amount_capturable: 0,
  amount_details: { tip: {} },
  amount_received: 200,
  application: null,
  application_fee_amount: null,
  automatic_payment_methods: null,
  canceled_at: null,
  cancellation_reason: null,
  capture_method: 'automatic',
  client_secret: 'my client secret',
  confirmation_method: 'automatic',
  created: 1707858316,
  currency: 'usd',
  customer: 'cus_PXktguxLe9CPK5',
  description: null,
  invoice: null,
  last_payment_error: null,
  latest_charge: 'ch_3OjTAGAHrCXdaN2D1BItzw31',
  livemode: false,
  metadata: {},
  next_action: null,
  on_behalf_of: null,
  payment_method: 'pm_1OifU1AHrCXdaN2DG1OBT7TR',
  payment_method_configuration_details: null,
  payment_method_options: {
    card: {
      installments: null,
      mandate_options: null,
      network: null,
      request_three_d_secure: 'automatic'
    }
  },
  payment_method_types: [ 'card' ],
  processing: null,
  receipt_email: null,
  review: null,
  setup_future_usage: null,
  shipping: null,
  source: null,
  statement_descriptor: null,
  statement_descriptor_suffix: null,
  status: 'succeeded',
  transfer_data: null,
  transfer_group: null
}
stripe customer id cus_PXktguxLe9CPK5
retrieving customer {
  id: 'cus_PXktguxLe9CPK5',
  object: 'customer',
  address: null,
  balance: 0,
  created: 1707666931,
  currency: 'usd',
  default_source: null,
  delinquent: false,
  description: null,
  discount: null,
  email: 'myemail',
  invoice_prefix: '74DD2FE8',
  invoice_settings: {
    custom_fields: null,
    default_payment_method: null,
    footer: null,
    rendering_options: null
  },
  livemode: false,
  metadata: {},
  name: 'my name',
  phone: null,
  preferred_locales: [],
  shipping: null,
  tax_exempt: 'none',
  test_clock: null
}
Customer email is my email
retrieving sessionId pi_3OjTAGAHrCXdaN2D11vQGxvG
```

Here it is the stripe payments dashboard [image]

The error itself => `file:///C:/Users/anon/folder/folder/folder/folder/stripe/esm/Error.js:7                                                    return new StripeInvalidRequestError(rawStripeError);                                                                          ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                            StripeInvalidRequestError: No such checkout.session: pi_3OjTAGAHrCXdaN2D11vQGxvG                                          at StripeError.generate (file:///C:/Users/folders/folder/folder/folder/folder`

Here is my server.js webhooks endpoint

```
// Stripe webhooks!
app.post('/stripe/webhooks', express.raw({type: 'application/json'}), async (req, res) => {
  const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
  let event;

  // Function to update plan in supabase db
  const updateUserPlan = async (customerEmail) => {
    console.log("Trying to update user plan using the updateUserPlan function");
    try {
      console.log("inside of updateUserPlan try block");

      const { data: updateData, error: updateError } = await supabase
      .from('accounts')
      .update({ Plan: 'Standard' })
      .eq('email', customerEmail)

      if (updateError) {
        console.error("Error updating user plan", updateError);
      }

      if (updateData) {
        console.log("updated user plan", updateData);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error with the updating userplan function", error);
    }
  }

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, sig, webhookSecret);
  }
  catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${error.message}`);
  }
  // Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded': {
      const paymentIntentSucceeded = event.data.object;
      console.log("webhooks: payment succeeded", paymentIntentSucceeded);

      // Get the customer ID from the payment intent
      const customerId = paymentIntentSucceeded.customer;

      console.log("stripe customer id", customerId);

      // Retrieve the customer object from the Stripe API
      const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(customerId);
      console.log("retrieving customer", customer);

      // Get the email from the customer object
      const customerEmail = customer.email;

      // Do something with the email, such as sending a receipt or a confirmation
      console.log("Customer email is", customerEmail);

      // Get the checkout session ID from the payment intent metadata
      const sessionId = paymentIntentSucceeded.id;
      console.log("retrieving sessionId", sessionId);
      // Retrieve the checkout session object from the Stripe API
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(sessionId);
      console.log("session:", session);

      console.log("checking subscription mode!")
      // Check the mode of the checkout session
      if (session.mode === "subscription") {
        // Only update the user plan if the mode is subscription
        console.log("checkout mode is subscription")
        updateUserPlan(customerEmail);
      } else {
        console.log("Skipping user plan update for payment mode");
      }
      break;
    }
    default:
      // Unexpected event type
      return res.status(400).end();
  }
  // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  res.status(200).send("webhook recieved request.");
})
```

And here is my server.js endpoint where I create the checkout session

```
// Endpoint to create checkout sessions for one-off payments
app.post("/create-checkout-payment", jsonParser, urlencodedParser, async (req, res) => {
  const { customerId, priceId } = req.body;
  console.log("recieved customer and priceid for credits", customerId, priceId);

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    customer: customerId,
    payment_method_types: [
      "card",
    ],
    line_items: [
      {
        price: priceId,
        quantity: 1
      }
    ],
    mode: "payment",
    success_url: 'https://localhost:5173/payment/success', // TODO: replace with real url
    cancel_url: 'https://localhost:5173/pricing', // TODO: replace with real url
  })
  res.json({ id: session.id })
```

Also here is my client side where I send the request if it helps at all

```
const stripe = useStripe();
  const customerID = props.stripeID;

  // Handling button click for 20 credits
  const handlePaymentClick20 = async () => {
    // Calling backend to create checkout session
    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/create-checkout-payment", {
      customerId: customerID,
      priceId: "price_1OjOgPAHrCXdaN2DTPp5dYWe",
    });
    console.log("Sent credits payment req", response);
    console.log("customerId in creditcard", customerID);

    // Redirecting to stripe checkout page
    if (response.data.id) {
      const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId: response.data.id,
      });
      if (error) {
        console.log("error getting stripe session id", error);
      }
    } else {
      console.error("No session id returned from backend");
    }
  }

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXQ0N.pn
```

I have verified that I use the correct API keys for both client and serverside. Any help would be very helpful as i've been stuck on this for a while now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using the ID for the related [Payment Intent](https://docs.stripe.com/payments/payment-intents).  The [Checkout Session](https://docs.stripe.com/payments/checkout/how-checkout-works) creates a Payment Intent when the customer pays.  In your webhook listening code you are listening for `payment_intent.succeeded`.  This [webhook event](https://docs.stripe.com/api/events/types#event_types-payment_intent.succeeded) will include a Payment Intent object in it's `data.object` property.

So in this part of your code:

```
 const sessionId = paymentIntentSucceeded.id;
 console.log("retrieving sessionId", sessionId);
 // Retrieve the checkout session object from the Stripe API
 const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(sessionId);
```

You are attempting to retrieve a Checkout Session using the ID for the Payment Intent.  For reference, all Payment Intent IDs start with `pi_` and all Checkout Session IDs start with `cs_`.

Now, as to what to do about it.  You have two options:

1. Change the [event type](https://docs.stripe.com/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed) you listen for to `checkout.session.completed`.  This event will return the Checkout Session in the `data.object` property.
2. You can use the [Checkout Session List API](https://docs.stripe.com/api/checkout/sessions/list#list_checkout_sessions-payment_intent) and filter by providing the ID as the `payment_intent` parameter.

Either approach will get you the Checkout Session object you are looking for.

Comment: Cheers I will try this and report back with the results.